# Display data from last row to first row

Tags: php, mysql

I searched a lot on stackoverflow as well as google, but there is no direct answer of my problem. It's a very basic problem so I think there must be a very simple solution but truly I can't find my solution, may be my search keywords are not perfect. So here the problem goes,

I am working with php & mysql now. I have a data table, I just want to display them from last row to first row and that's all about my problem.

Comment: How do you define which row is first and which one is last?

Comment: I have an auto increment as well as primary key column named ID. So can't I use this column to detect the first or last row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
     $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job ORDER BY id DESC");
       while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        echo $row1['id']." <br /> " ;     
    }
```

output :

```
19
18
17
......
```

// the id is your column name

Comment: hope is this what you are looking for

Comment: I see. Let me check. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thanks. Another help, suppose my code is $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event
WHERE Tarikh='$dm'"); now, notice a WHERE condition? I can't put ORDER BY in this code. Is there any way?

Comment: yes u can put the order by in the end . nice that it solved your problem , please consider to accept the answer as it helped you , any thing else u welcome to post new post

Comment: it will be `$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event WHERE Tarikh='$dm' ORDER BY .... "); `

Comment: Thanks for your time. You mean Vote up? Yes I did it already. :)

Comment: no not vote up , i mean accept it by clicking the tick accept under the vote